# Django tracking tags in different languages

Tags: django, arabic

I've built a small app into my project which is intended to go through given text and extract words with # tag before it.

When text is received in English it works perfectly but when using Arabic or Chinese it won't work. Any idea how can I make it adapt foreign languages as well?

in my model.py I wrote

```
class Article(models.Model):

def _strip_hash_tags(self, ):
    return tuple([tag.strip("#") for tag in self.content.split() if tag.startswith("#")])

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
    super(Article, self).save(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using)

    # first remove all associatd tags with object
    Tag.objects.remove_all_tags(self)
    # then, look through content field and insert all tagged words
    for tag in self._strip_hash_tags():
        Tag.objects.add_tag(self, tag)
```